# Error while trying to replay a Gnosis Safe creation on Polygon network

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a safe wallet on Polygon network with the "2 out of 3 owners" validation.
My issue is that 2 of the 3 owners are Safe wallet created on the Gnosis chain (Nest safes).
So I'm trying to replay on Polygon Mainnet the Safe Wallet creation transaction that was executed on Gnosis to have the ability to change the owner (and validate any transaction).

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741)

But my [transaction failed](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x940d46d3698861cd13d36ec7684accc13a8e69fab8b83273713eb020554a17e7) :

I followed the steps and sent a transaction on the **Polygon Mainnet** to this address : `0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2`

This hash (from the [original transaction on Gnosis](https://gnosisscan.io/tx/0xdafcdfbb889d8bd349a416768e14c4d2e382c49c6a80c8c11144d77816399540)) :

```
0x4522589f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002010ebfafa92366fc788856586781424e792a883c6613a5f55817f87d8d2185cbb000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054000000000000000000000000075ba5af8effdcfca32e1e288806d54277d1fde9900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064df6b5d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064df6ee1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038427be3c2400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e00000000000000000000000008acbfeef6ff6e77a1e44f0d88e3385b6fb488ea70000000000000000000000002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa841740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000089000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000379481ce2b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032ae72c00d4b7a37a37910ebfafa92366fc788856586781424e792a883c6613a5f55817f87d8d2185cbb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064000000000000000000000000a6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002041688f0b90000000000000000000000003e5c63644e683549055b9be8653de26e0b4cd36e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060289d215af145fedb430714659667044af684d6255ea4dcbe82d7262d7f09e1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164b63e800d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000000000000000f48f2b2d2a534e402487b3ee7c18c33aec0fe5e4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000082c5d602af53c2428f98db6823643fc4fe597b720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004192c8243eee7614e446d267da5e599fe70112aaa27ff4300ced4f74012eefd9ab61faa507b34d6b44000f44de3320231ed360ea9847ac8ddc83f21f5681efeeb51c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041589f6cdea77c41a62cbf840de65939c5bde521af367b1f3ad4a46261b4a2ecc469da18455d335e9037e68a6d06b43ff0411cd65763e68e2813e9cf54bb422d3d1b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Any idea why it failed ?

Thanks guys

Comment: It looks like the function wasn't in the contract you sent (https://polygonscan.com/address/0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2#code).